# HttpClientHandler NetworkCredential vs DefaultCredentials

Tags: c#, http, windows-authentication

If I create a `HttpClient` with a `HttpClientHandler` that has `UseDefaultCredentials=true`, everything is fine.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler{ UseDefaultCredentials = true };
```

However, if I instead have my `HttpClientHandler` defined as

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("someuser", "pw", "somedomain");
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
```

I get an exception when trying to send:

> Win32Exception: The target principal name is incorrect

Even though the user for `DefaultCredentials` on the server is reported as "somedomain\someuser". Do I need to call something to validate the credentials somehow before adding the to my handler?

Both client and server run on my PC. The user (in both cases) is my windows user, that I'm logged in with (domain user).

Comment: If the first code sample works, why bother trying the latter?

Comment: Because I need to be able to specify a user/pw. We have a service that must run as Localhost, but we must connect  as a specific domain user. The service runs on a server with no user logged in